# Organizing multiples p-values in R (kruskal.test)

Tags: r

Using the code below I’ve created a data.frame() with 5 variables. In this way I can obtain the value of p using kruskal.test().

```
> sample1 <- c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3)
> sample2 <- c(7, 7, 10, 6, 10)
> sample3 <- c(10, 13, 12, 14, 13)
> sample4 <- c(15, 20, 18, 20, 17)
> sample5 <- c(4, 5, 3, 3, 4)
> table <- data.frame(sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4, sample5)
> 
> kruskal.test(sample1,sample2)$p.value
[1] 0.1353353
> kruskal.test(sample1,sample3)$p.value
[1] 0.2614641
> kruskal.test(sample1,sample4)$p.value
[1] 0.6822703
> kruskal.test(sample1,sample5)$p.value
[1] 0.4723666
```

However, I’d like to organize the results in a data.frame() with all the possibilities of p-value that is similar to the image below, using ‘table’ variable.

[image]

Is there a package, a commando or an alternative that could make this happen? I’ve seen something similar using the cor() function, but I couldn’t find anything that could be applied on my case until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `outer()` to help here. It takes all combinations of values that you pass in. For exampl

```
pvals <- outer(table, table, function(x,y) {
  mapply(function(x,y) kruskal.test(x,y)$p.value, x,y)
})

diag(pvals) <- NA
pvals
```

which returns

```
          sample1   sample2   sample3   sample4   sample5
sample1        NA 0.1353353 0.2614641 0.6822703 0.4723666
sample2 0.1360371        NA 0.3748093 0.3207621 0.8232919
sample3 0.1467931 0.3311237        NA 0.3173651 0.6738573
sample4 0.2765005 0.5459307 0.4429172        NA 0.1905397
sample5 0.2635525 0.2710219 0.3207621 0.7344166        NA
```

Comment: I have no words to thank you. You were sensational. I will study more about the functions you used.